# How to keep all the elements within container using flexbox?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to get all the letters displayed within container evenly spaced out using flexbox. Right now, if I enter sentence like "I like learning code", all elements are displayed within container and works ok, but if I use long word like "refrigerator", letters comes out of container. But I'm trying to keep all the letters to stay within container no matter how long the word is. I tried all the available flexbox techniques, but no luck. Tried max-width on container too. What am I missing? Here is the code in code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-sun-3u7b3?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  // let sentence = "I like learning code";
  let sentence = "refrigerator";
  const words = sentence.split(" ");

  return (
    <div className="pageContainer">
      {words.map((word, i) => (
        <div className="row" key={i}>
          {[...word].map((letter) => (
            <p className="letterBorder">{letter}</p>
          ))}
          {i === words.length - 1 ? null : <p className="whiteSpaceBorder"></p>}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
.letterBorder {
  border: 25px;
  background: grey;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  min-width: 100%;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.whiteSpaceBorder {
  border: 25px;
  background: orange;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.pageContainer {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightcyan;
  height: 40rem;
  width: 30rem;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is due to the hardcoded horizontal padding of your letterBorder class.

Replace

```
padding: 20px;
```

with

```
  padding: 20px 0;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-violet-qg1xt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you. Extra 0 was all I needed... Never knew padding could impact flexbox. Thank you for valuable lesson.

Comment: The padding is not really impacting the flexbox.
Flexbox defines the height, width and position of your items, and the padding adds some space between them, making them exceed the border of the container.

Answer (score 0):

This is where the css property `flex-wrap` comes in handy. Flexbox items all try to fit into one line by default. However, you can make them wrap using `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Add it to your row class:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow items in row to "wrap" to next line if needed */
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  min-width: 100%;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
```

See [this css-tricks page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a better visual explanation.

Comment: Actually I need refrigerator fit into container as 1 row. Wrapping  creates 3 rows in order to fit refrigerator. So one word per row is what I'm trying to achieve. But if word is too long like refrigerator, it gets out of container.

Comment: Ah, got it. The other answer describing changing letterBorder padding to `20px 0` should do the trick.